# ESLint error when using optional catch binding

Tags: node.js, eslint

With this code:

```
try {

} catch {

}
```

ESLint gives this error:

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token {
```

Is there an ESLint rule to enable optional catch binding?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an ES2019 feature, so make sure you set an `ecmaVersion` of 10. For example, your `.eslintrc.json` [should have](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring):

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 10
    }
}
```

> Setting parser options helps ESLint determine what is a parsing error.

Similarly, for the [online demo](https://eslint.org/demo), make sure to select `2019` from the "ECMA Version" dropdown list.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason

```json
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 10
    }
}
```

did not work for me.

But this did:

```json
"rules": {
  "no-empty": ["error", { "allowEmptyCatch": true }]
},
```

For more info see https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-empty#allowemptycatch